# Unix networking programming

Tags: c, unix-socket

I have written a client-server program which does some data from a file in server to the client. In this I don't want the client to wait indefinitely if server is not running. For this I am using SELECT system call, in this system call we can specify timings as an argument, which tells the client to waits for the server to send the data within that time. Now the problem is, it's sending the data oly for that no. of seconds(as specified in select() ). It's not doing the actual work..
NOTE:- I am using UDP connection.

Can Anyone solve this problem??

Comment: Note that UDP is a [connectionless protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Comparison_of_UDP_and_TCP).

Answer (score 0):

You do actually `read` after `select` returns? You must `read` from the fd that `select` marked.